# Как разделить класс на cpp и .h при имеющимся template?

Tags: c++

Не совсем понимаю как можно вынести из .h файла подобный класс так, чтобы не было кучи ошибок с темплейтом, ведь переопределять класс нельзя. Попросил бы кого-то показать элементарный пример как выглядеть будет код ниже, разбитый на два файла. 1 код - все вместе, и функция, которую нужно перенести, 2 код - мой .h файл. Заранее благодарю.

```
template<typename T> //template for ComparisonCountingSort
class CountingSort {
public: 
    vector<T> intVector;
    vector<int> counter;
    vector<T> sum;
    int max;

    void InitVector(vector<T> vect) { // initializing our vectors
        intVector = vect;
        counter.clear();             // clear vector 
        max = *max_element(vect.begin(), vect.end()); 
        for (int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++) {
            counter.push_back(0);      // init for DistributionCountingSort
        }
    }
}
```

```
template<typename T> //template for ComparisonCountingSort
class CountingSort {
public: 
    vector<T> intVector;
    vector<int> counter;
    vector<T> sum;
    int max;

    void InitVector(vector<T> vect);
}
```

Comment: Во второй пример кода добавьте **в конец** `#include "counting_sort.inl"`. И в этом файле добавляйте определения шаблонных методов (так же, как если бы они были бы в том же файле, но вне класса).

Comment: С большой вероятностью разделение на .cpp и .h в этом случае не нужно. Не стоит это делать просто по привычке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шаблонные методы должны присутствовать при компиляции любых `.cpp` файлов, чтобы компилятор смог для каждого случая сделать свой экземпляр метода.
Можно разделить ваш первый большой код на два заголовочных `.h` файла. В первом - объявление класса с его *предварительно* объявленными методами, и второй - с этими *реальными* кодами методов.
Просто в конце первого хедера добавьте с помощью `# include` второй файл.

CountingSort.h :

```
template<typename T> //template for ComparisonCountingSort
class CountingSort {
public: 
    vector<T> intVector;
    vector<int> counter;
    vector<T> sum;
    int max;

    void InitVector(vector<T> vect);
} ;
# include "CountingSort_impl.h"
```

CountingSort_impl.h :

```
template<typename T>
void CountingSort<T>::InitVector(vector<T> vect) { // initializing our vectors
    intVector = vect;
    counter.clear();             // clear vector 
    max = *max_element(vect.begin(), vect.end()); 
    for (int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++) {
        counter.push_back(0);      // init for DistributionCountingSort
    }
}
```

и для всех `.cpp` фалов, кому он нужен просто делать *одно* включение хедера :

```
# include "CountingSort.h"
```

*Данное разделение файла предназначено для комфортного обзора методов класса, типов аргументов, спецификаторов и т.д. Это рекомендуется как для шаблонов так и для обыкновенных классов. А если у двух классов существуют методы, использующие друг друга - то такое требование обязательно.*

Comment: Стоило бы пояснить, зачем в теории может понадобится такое разделение на два файла, так как в вопросе наличие такой необходимости не фигурирует.